# Alternative to create element a href in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, href

I have the following **JavaScript** code that **works correctly**.

```
var powered = "Example"
var URL_powered = 'http://www.example.com/api.aspx';
// Powered by link a href...
document.getElementById('powered_by').innerHTML = '<a href="'+URL_powered+'"' + ' target="_blank" rel="noopener">'+powered+'</a>';
```

**Result:**

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/api.aspx" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Example</a>
```

Now I am using a string to set this element because I tried in various ways and I couldn't add all  attributes to `document.createElement`.

I must comment that this element is dynamicm elsewhere in the code it changes value, but the same structure is used.

I don't want HTML nor jQuery solutions.

**In summary:**

I want to get the exact same result that I showed above but using `document.createElement ('a')` in **JavaScript** code.

Comment: you can add an event listener to the document that when clicked, it changes the url. `element.addEventListener('click', () => { window.location.href = 'google.com' })`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @kibe, but I'm not looking for that solution, I want to do it with variables and using `document.createElement ('a')`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. It sets properties, since those ones map to their associated attribute.

I added the serialized HTML to the document so you can see what gets rendered.

```js
var powered = "Example";
var URL_powered = 'http://www.example.com/api.aspx';

var a = document.getElementById('powered_by')
  .appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
  
a.href = URL_powered;
a.target = "_blank";
a.rel = "noopener";
a.textContent = powered;

document.querySelector("pre")
  .textContent = a.outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id=powered_by></div>

<pre></pre>
```

---

Not a bad idea to make a function that automates this a bit.

```js
var powered = "Example";
var URL_powered = 'http://www.example.com/api.aspx';
var a = document.getElementById('powered_by')
  .appendChild(createElement("a", {
    href: URL_powered,
    target: "_blank",
    rel: "noopener",
    textContent: powered,
  }));

document.querySelector("pre")
  .textContent = a.outerHTML;



function createElement(name, props) {
  var el = document.createElement(name);
  for (var p in props) {
    el[p] = props[p];
  }
  return el;
}
```

```html
<div id=powered_by></div>

<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I wanted! Thank you very much @slappy :)
Too bad I don't have enough reputation to mark this solution as the best.

Comment: @Juan: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the exact same result.

`href` set the value as resolved URL from any input. `setAttribute('href')` set the value as is:

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = '/foo/'; // [1]
a.setAttribute('href', '/foo/'); // [2]

document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = a.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example using createElement and appendChild.

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.example.com/api.aspx';
a.target = '_blank';
a.text = 'Example';
a.rel = 'Example';
document.getElementById('powered_by').appendChild(a);
```

Output:

```
<div id="powered_by"><a href="http://www.example.com/api.aspx" target="_blank" rel="Example">Example</a></div>
```